# Run stored procedure to populate an existing table from an MVC Controller

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

The following SQL code works perfectly in [QTY] database. it deletes all the rows in [Table1], then runs the stored procedure [test] and inserts the result into [Table1].

I want to be able to run this code from an MVC controller. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

```
USE [QTY]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

Delete from Table1

INSERT INTO Table1

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[test]
        @Month = N'M4',
        @Forecast = '2019-04-30'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `FromSql` method which enables you to pass in a SQL command to be executed against the database to return instances of the type represented by the `DbSet` .

```
// Format string
var author = db.Authors.FromSql("SELECT * From Authors Where AuthorId = {0}", id).FirstOrDefault();
// String interpolation
var author = db.Authors.FromSql($"SELECT * From Authors Where AuthorId = {id}").FirstOrDefault();
```

The DbContext exposes a `Database` property which includes a method called `ExecuteSqlCommand`. This method returns an integer specifying the number of rows affected by the SQL statement passed to it.

```
using(var context = new SampleContext())
{ 
   var commandText = "INSERT Categories (CategoryName) VALUES (@CategoryName)";
   var name = new SqlParameter("@CategoryName", "Test");
   context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, name);
}
```

You could take some time on the tutorial [Executing Raw SQL Queries](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql)